# Как отправить через telebot аудио с локальных дисков

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pycharm, telebot

У меня такой вопрос можно ли отправить аудио с локального диска. Пытаюсь но не получается.
Я использую `Python`, `telebot`.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'При':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, мой создатель')
    elif message.text == 'hello':
        bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, 'C:\Program Files (x86)\bit\1.ogg')
    elif message.text == 'Ясно!!!':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAMhXrEiC5rUiGT-ceiKkmiwjJou1xIAAg8DAAJtsEIDDrRMZLudXUYZBA')
```

Вот код но не получается отправить. 
Вот ошибка:

```
raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result) telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body: [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL specified"}'] " 2020-05-08 20:19:25,300 (__init__.py:443 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body: [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL specified"}']"
```

Answer (score 1):

откройте файл перед отправкой, а после закройте

```
audio = open(r'W:\Music\music\1_VIZE - Stars.mp3', 'rb')
bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio)
audio.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

можно так, у меня работает:

```
with open(r'D:\python\output.mp3', 'rb') as audio:
    bot.send_audio(message.from_user.id, audio)
```